# Make a new line after 3 character after regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have following list:

```
Intel(USA)
Pfizer(USA)6
GeneralElectric(USA)43
Alphabet(Google)(USA)
```

I can select latest `(` in each line by `^.*\K\((?=[^(]*$)` regex.
Now I want to make a new line after 3 character after my regex.
for example I get following result:

```
Intel(USA
)  
Pfizer(USA
)6  
GeneralElectric(USA
)43  
Alphabet(Google)(USA
)
```

how to do this by regex and what changes I must apply to my regex?
Note that for some reason I must create a regex for latest `(` and can't use latest `)` **and note that provide regex for Notepad++**

Comment: Are `(`s and `)`s always balanced on the same line without any nesting?

Comment: @anubhava yes .

Comment: Ten why not match `^.+\K\)` and replace with `\n)` ?

Comment: @anubhava for some reason I must create a regex for latest ( and can't use latest ) and some lines in my list have not )

Comment: Precisely the reason I posted my first comment :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match until the last `(` and then match optional chars other than `(` and `)`

Then forget what is matched so far, and assert the closing `)`

In the replacement use a newline.

```
^.*\([^()\r\n]*\K(?=\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2gebJ/1)

Or match 3 chars A-Z

```
^.*\([A-Z]{3}\K(?=\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WoodSn/1)

[image]

Comment: Much better than the 3 char requirement

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, but now that you mention it..let me add that one as well.

Comment: not working your regex!

Comment: I edited my post. read latest post line again please

Comment: @PubgMobile See screenshot

Comment: Note that for some reason I must create a regex for latest ( and can't use latest )

Comment: @PubgMobile What do you mean by latest? Does it work for the example strings in the question? Like this? `^.*\([A-Z]{3}\K(?=[^\r\n(]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/fVMMNc/1

Comment: You gave a good idea.